# What is Sri Ganesh Gita?

Tags: ganesha, gita

Like we have Lord Krishna's Bhagavad Gita, did Lord Ganesha also give a teaching of Gita? If yes, to whom?

It is said that both Bhagavad Gita and Ganesh Gita are the same, with the only difference being that the preachers are different. Is it so?

What are the importance and significance of the Ganesh Gita? What does Ganesh Gita tell all about?

Comment: do you understand what the word 'Gita' means?

Comment: Gita means song BTW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is from the Ganesha Purana. It was told to a king called Varenya by Lord Ganesha himself.

You can read it from [this page](http://www.astrojyoti.com/ganeshagita.htm).

> Varenya said, ‘In the world of birth and death many difficulties
>   arise, and they are very hard to endure. Remover of obstacles, kindly
>   show me the path to liberation now. How can there be bondage in the
>   realization of You, Dviradnana. Declare to me that teaching by which I
>   will attain liberation, that yoga through which I will give up desire,
>   anger and the fear of death.’
>
> Brahma said, “**After having listened to this speech, Gajanana kindly
>   sat Varenya on a comfortable seat and placed his hand on his head.
>   Then he began to teach him the Ganesha Gita**, casting away all his
>   doubts by presenting His universal form. As soon as he understood the
>   essence of the Gita from Ganesha’s instruction and having transferred
>   the kingdom to his ministers, he went to the forest. Filled with
>   detachment, the accomplished King meditated on Gajanana, fixed on
>   nothing else, and always preached the Gita. Just as water thrown into
>   water stays only as water, so he came to consist of Him by meditating
>   on Him.’

Also, there are many Gitas that are found in the Puranas. And, all of them preach more or less the same things. So, if you have read one of them, then you kind of already know what to find in the others.

For example, Iswara Gita (which is found in the Kurma Purana) is exactly the same as the Gita that is found in Mahabharata, with the only difference being that one is in the words of Parama Shiva while the other in those of Krishna.