# How many Gitas are there?

Tags: gita

We all know about Srimad Bhagavad Gita. Naively, I thought this was the only Gita we have.

But, to my surprise, yesterday I found "The Song of the Goddess - Devi Gita". This is basically the last 10 chapters (31-40) of the 7th Canto of the Devi Bhagavad Purana. This is a canonical Sakta text. But, I guess it is not as popular as Srimad Bhagavad Gita.

The question that bugs me since then is, do we have many more Gitas? Exactly how many Gitas we have? Is it that each denomination in Hinduism has its own Gita? Can someone list the name of all the Gitas along with short descriptions (if possible)?

Comment: There is the ashtavakra gita. The Ashtavakra Gita or Song of Ashtavakra is a classical text in the Advaita Vedanta tradition in the form of a dialogue between the sage Ashtavakra and Janaka, king of Mithila. Then there is the Uddhav Gita, spoken by Krishna to Uddhav before departing from this world.

Comment: There are many other Gitas - Anugita (Mahabharata itself), Shiva Gita (some version of Padma Purāṇa I think), Devi Gita (Devi Bhagavatam), Brahma Gita (Skanda Purāṇa describes Brahman), as many as 5 Gitas in the Srimad Bhagavatam itself, Rama Gita (Adhyatma Ramayanam not from the Purāṇa). More than sampradayik in nature, these are from the entire corpus of the Puranas by Vyasa; for the purpose of understanding Brahman. The Brahma Gita in Skanda Purāṇa is supposed to be very significant because it helps in understanding the Aitareya Upanishad better (I’ve not read any so can’t comment on this)

Comment: On [this page](https://www.astrojyoti.com/scripturesindex.htm) they have listed around 30 gitas that are found in various Hindu scriptures (mostly in Puranas).

Comment: @Adiyarkku ... Does this Brahma Gita taken from Skanda purana describes the four-headed deity brahma or the nirguna nirakara Brahman? Thnx.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse, haha no it’s not chaturanana Brahmaji. It’s Brahman as specified in the brackets above. To be more specific it’ll be related to Lord Shiva but may have aspects of Nirgunaness as well. A word of caution this isn’t found in the [colonial version](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/who-edited-the-puranas) of the Skanda Purāṇa. It’s found in the traditional Samhita version which you can read about [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/what-is-the-correspondence-between-khandas-and-samhitas-in-the-skanda-purana/40498#40498)

Comment: Well, there are many Gitas, but none of them brought attention of so many scholars, commentators, and learned men, and people in general, public, as Bhagavad gita did. Thus Bhagavad gita was and stays to be most famous of them all, and most influential among them all as well. That's for sure.

Comment: The general translation of gita is song, there is nothing peculiar about the designation, nor is there any one authority for what is designated as a 'gita'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although 'the Śrīmad Bhagavad Gītā' of the Bhīṣma Parva in the Mahābhārata remains by far the most popular, nonetheless, there are umpteen Gītās - some of which are well-known, and other's might be never heard of.

Here, I'm compiling a tabular compilation list of various Gītās from different sources.

---

- ### Vaiṣṇava Sect

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Śrīmada Bhagavada Gītā | Mahābhārata | Krṣṇa (Viṣṇu) | Arjuna | Kavi Gītā Hari Gītā Viṣṇu Gītā Krṣṇa Gita | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/ahpp8n3k), [2](https://tinyurl.com/4fayvpy3) English: [1](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/), [2](https://archive.org/details/bhagavadgitawith00lond/page/n9/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookShrimadBhagwatGita/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-shrimadBhagwatGitaWithTika.pdf/page/n49/mode/2up) [All Three](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.279/page/n7/mode/2up) |
| 2. | Uttara Gītā | Mahābhārata (Aśvemedha Parva) | Krṣṇa | Arjuna | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/4mapmhmc), [2](https://tinyurl.com/4wjf5mh8) English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/4fe5dvc4) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/4fe5dvc4) |
| 3. | Arjunopākhyāna | Yoga Vāsiṣṭha (Nirvāṇa Prakaraṇa) (Purvārdha): Sargas 52 to 58 | Krṣṇa [Vasiṣṭha] | Arjuna [Rāma] | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2c6fnx38) English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/24kr7du7): Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/yogavasisthaofmahakavivalmikivol.iiidr.mahaprabhulalgoswami/page/n544/mode/1up?view=theater) |
| 4. | Anu Gītā | Mahābhārata (Aśvemedhika Parva) | Krṣṇa | Arjuna | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2bxj3kz9) English: [1](https://archive.org/details/Anugita/mode/2up), [2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826511.html), [3](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n3051/mode/2up?view=theater) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/14-18%20Mahabharat%20Asvamedhika%20to%20Svargarohana%20Parvas%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201958/page/n59/mode/2up?view=theater), [2](https://archive.org/details/mahabharata06ramauoft/page/780/mode/2up) |
| 5. | Śrī Viṣṇu Gītā | Independent Work | Viṣṇu | All other deities | - | Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-shri-vishnu-gita/page/n3/mode/2up) |
| 6. | Vaiṣṇava Gītā | Independent Work | Krṣṇa | Arjuna | - | - |
| 7. | Śrī Rāma Gītā -1 | Adhyātma Rāmāyaṇa | Śrī Rāma (Siva) | Laksmana (Parvati) | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2p897a5d) English: [1](https://archive.org/details/TheAdhyatmaRamayana/page/n213/mode/2up), Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/AdhyatmaRamayana/page/n381/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/page/n375/mode/2up?view=theater) |
| 8. | Śrī Rāma Gītā -2 | Tattvasaṁgraha (by Ṛṣi Vasiṣṭha) | Śrī Rāma | Hanumāna | - | Hindi - [1](https://archive.org/details/ShriRamGitaDungarpurNareshVijaySinghBahadur/page/n1/mode/2up) |
| 9. | Śrī Rāma Gītā -3 | Skanda Purāṇa (saṁhitā version) | Śukadeva | Sanatkumar | - | Unavailable |
| 10. | Śrī Rāma Gītā -4 | Adbhuta Rāmāyaṇa | Śrī Rāma | Hanumāna | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/mumss3pm) English: [1](https://archive.org/details/adbhut_ramayan/page/n73/mode/2up), Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2pk9e5jn), [2](https://archive.org/details/adbhut-ramayan-pt-jwala-prasad-mishra/page/n65/mode/2up) |

- ### Śaiva Sect:

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Śiva Gītā | Padma Purāṇa (non-extant version) | Śiva (Rudra) | Śrī Rāma | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/35kwzajf), English: [1](https://archive.org/details/siva-gita-1997/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/shiv-gita-pt.-jwala-prasad-mishra), [2](https://archive.org/details/ShriShivaGeetaSwamiIshvaranandaGiri/page/n3/mode/2up) |
| 2. | Īśvara Gītā | Kurma Purāṇa | Śiva | Various Deities | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yhhhweam) English: [1](https://archive.org/details/kurma-purana-full-parts-1-and-2/page/n355/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.406605/page/n351/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/IshwarGitaDatiaSwami_201710/mode/2up), [2](https://tinyurl.com/2pk9e5jn) |
| 3. | Rudra Gītā - 1 | Srimada Bhagvatama Purāṇa | Rudra (Śiva) | Pracehtas | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/zvrhd6x3), [2](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/24/16/) English: [1](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n577/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n459/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.232200/page/n575/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/srimad-bhagavat-mahapuran-2-volume-set-sanskrit-hindi/Srimad%20Bhagavat%20Mahapuran%20Volume%201%20Sanskrit%20Hindi/page/n857/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/sb_hindi/page/n303/mode/2up) |
| 4. | Rudra Gītā - 2 | Varaha Purāṇa | Rudra (Śiva) | Mahaṛṣi Agastya | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yhhhweam) English: [1](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12962/page/n179/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/puran_varah/page/n113/mode/2up?view=theater) |
| 5. | Brahma Gītā | Skanda Purāṇa (Sūta Sahiṃtā) | Brahmā | Various deities | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/5ezf8wyz) |
| 6. | Sūta Gītā | Skanda Purāṇa (Sūta Sahiṃtā) | Sūta | Various Sages | - | Sanskrit :[1](https://tinyurl.com/2umben4e) |
| 7. | Śrī Śhambhu Gītā | Independent work | Sadaśiva (Vyāsa) | Pitṛs (Sūta) | - | Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/wg997/mode/2up) |

- ### Śakta Sect

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Devī Gītā | Devī Bhāgvata Purāṇa | Ādi Śakti | Himāvana | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/mr2rsasr), [2](https://archive.org/details/devi-gita-with-tika-of-nilakantha-1919-khemraj/Bhagavati%20Gita%20with%20Nilakantha%27s%20Tika%20-%20Maheshdatt%20Sukul%201895/mode/2up) English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57422.html) [2](https://archive.org/details/devi-gita/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/DeviBhagavataWithHindiTranslationVolume2GitaPress/page/n173/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/devi-gita-with-tika-of-nilakantha-1919-khemraj/Devi%20Gita%20from%20Devi%20Bhagavata%20Hindi%20-%20Jwalaprasad%20Mishra%201901/mode/2up) |
| 2. | Saptaśatī Gītā | Mārkanḍeya Purāṇa | Medha Muni | King Surath | Devī Māhātmyam Śrī Canḍī Gāthā Saptaśatī | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/38byryv6) English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117157.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/markandeyapurana021288mbp/page/332/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/durga-saptashati-geetapress), [2](https://archive.org/details/SriDurgaSaptashatiSantNagpal/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/markandeyapurana/page/n285/mode/2up) |
| 3. | Śrī Bhagavatī Gītā | MahāBhāgvata Purāṇa (An Upa-Purāṇa ) | Ādi Śakti [Mahādeva] | Himāvana [Nārada] | Pārvatī Gītā Gaṅgopākhyāna | English: [1](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/jspui/bitstream/10603/188643/14/14_chapter%208.pdf) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/devi-gita-with-tika-of-nilakantha-1919-khemraj/Parvati%20Gita%20from%20Mahabhagavata%20Upapurana/) [2](https://archive.org/details/sri-mahabhagavata-upapurana-acharya/S%CC%92ri_Mah%C4%81bh%C4%81gavata_Upapur%C4%81%E1%B9%87a_Acharya/page/n215/mode/2up), [3](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/bhagwati-gita-parvati-gita-old-and-rare-book-mzv293/) |
| 4. | Śrī Śakti Gītā | Independent Work | Devī (Vyāsa) | Various deities (Sūta) | - | Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/devi-gita-with-tika-of-nilakantha-1919-khemraj/Sakti%20Gita%20with%20Hindi%20Translation%201916%20%28BDMM%29/mode/2up) |

- ### Gāṇapatya Sect

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Gaṇeśa Gītā | Gaṇeśa Purāṇa | Bhagvān Gaṇeśa | Himāvana | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/ganeshagita.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/GaneshGita1906AnanadaAshramGranthavali/page/n1/mode/2up) English: [1](https://www.astrojyoti.com/ganeshagita.htm) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/page/n7/mode/2up?view=theater), [2](https://archive.org/details/ganesh_gita/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/ganesh-gita-pandit-jwala-prasad/mode/2up) |
| 2. | Dhīśa Gītā | Independent Work | Gaṇeśa (Vyasa) | Various sages (Suta) | - | Sanskrit:[1](https://archive.org/details/shri-dhish-gita-shri-bharat-dharma-mahamandal-varanasi/page/n5/mode/2up) English Hindi: [1](http://www.shdvef.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B6-%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE.pdf), [2](https://archive.org/details/shri-dhish-gita-shri-bharat-dharma-mahamandal-varanasi/mode/2up) |

- ### Saura Sect

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Sūrya Gītā - 1 | Guru-jñāna-vāsiṣṭha Tattva-sārāyaṇa Karmakāṇḍa | Bhagvān Sūrya [Dakṣiṇāmūrti] | Aruṇa (sārathī) [Brahmā] | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2fsvf6np) English: [1](http://surya-gita.blogspot.com/) Hindi: |
| 2. | Sūrya Gītā - 2 | Independent Work | Bhagvān Sūrya [Vyāsa] | Saptarṣi [Sūta] | - | Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/shri-surya-gita-damaged-pages-shri-bharat-dharm-mahamandal-varanasi/mode/2up) |

- ### Advaita-Vedānta

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Avadhuta Gītā | Independent work | Bhagvān Dattātreya | - | Datta-Gītā Advaita Gītā | Sanskrit: [1](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/minigita/avadhuta?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1), 2, 3 English: [1](https://archive.org/details/Avadhuta_Gita_with_English_Translation/AvadhutaGitaSanskritTextWithEnglishTranslation/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/AvadhutaGitaSwamiChetanananda/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/avadhutagitaofdattareyaswamiashokananda/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/page/n537/mode/2up?view=theater), [2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.345587/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-avadhoot-geeta.pdf/mode/2up) |
| 2. | Aṣtāvakra Gītā | Independent Work | Ṛṣi Aṣtāvakra | King Janaka | - | Sṅkṛt: [1](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/ashtgita.html), [2](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/minigita/ashtavakra?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1), [3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/ashtavakra-gita-sanskrit/d/doc345796.html), [4](http://www.sriramana.org/music/astavarkagita/Ashtavakra_Sanskrit.pdf) Eng.: [1](https://archive.org/details/ashtavakra-gita-by-swami-nityaswarupananda/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/AshtavakraGitaSanskritTextWithEnglishTransliterationTranslation_201506), [3](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.490169/page/n1/mode/2up), [4](http://www.sriramana.org/music/astavarkagita/Ashtavakra_Gita_Eng_Translation.pdf) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/page/n471/mode/2up?view=theater), [2](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAshtavakraGitaRamanandaSaraswati), [3](https://archive.org/details/AshtavakraGitaWithHindiTranslation1911KhemrajPublishers), [4](https://archive.org/details/ashtavakra-gita-sanskrit-hindi) |
| 3. | Siddha Gītā | Yoga Vāsiṣṭha (Upaśama Prakaraṇa) | Ṛṣi Vāsiṣṭha | Śrī Rāma | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/siddhagiitaa.html), [2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc258152.html) English: [2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118255.html), [3](https://www.astrojyoti.com/siddhagita.htm) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yynpp2x8) |
| 4. | Vāsiṣṭha Gītā | Yoga Vāsiṣṭha (Nirvāṇa Prakaraṇa) | Ṛṣi Vāsiṣṭha | Śrī Rāma | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc264017.html) English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118584.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/yogavasisthaofmahakavivalmikivol.iiidr.mahaprabhulalgoswami/page/n501/mode/2up) |
| 5. | Brahma Gītā | Yoga Vāsiṣṭha (Nirvāṇa Prakaraṇa Uttarārdha) | Ṛṣi Vāsiṣṭha | Śrī Rāma | - | Sanskrit: [1](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/brahmagItAyogavAsiShTha.html) English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc228870.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/yogavasisthaofmahakavivalmikivol.vdr.mahaprabhulalgoswami/page/n529/mode/2up) |
| 6. | Yajñavarāha Gitā | Guru-jñāna-vāsiṣṭha Tattva-sārāyaṇa Jñānakānḍa | Bhagvān Viṣṇu | Ṛbhu | - | - |

- ### From the Mahābhārata (Śanti Parva):

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Aśmaka Gitā | [Chapter 28 & 29] Rājdharma Parva | Ṛṣi Vyāsa | Yudhiṣṭhira | Aśmagitā | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc825985.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n2235/mode/2up?view=theater) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4480/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/12%20Mahabharat%20Santi%20Parva%20Part%201%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201929/page/n125/mode/2up?view=theater) |
| 2. | Utathya Gitā | Rājdharma Parva | Utathya [Bhiṣma] | King Yauvāśva [Yudhiṣṭhira] | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826046.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4656/mode/2up) |
| 3. | Vāmadeva Gitā | Rājdharma Parva | Vāmadeva [Bhiṣma] | King Vasumanas [Yudhiṣṭhira] | - | English: [1](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n2309/mode/2up?view=theater), [2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826048.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/12%20Mahabharat%20Santi%20Parva%20Part%201%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201929/page/n521/mode/2up?view=theater), [2](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4662/mode/2up) |
| 4. | Ṛṣabha Gitā | Rājdharma Parva | Sage Ṛṣabha [Bhiṣma] | King Sumitra [Yudhiṣṭhira] | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826081.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n2337/mode/2up?view=theater) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4746/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/12%20Mahabharat%20Santi%20Parva%20Part%201%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201929/page/n689/mode/2up?view=theater) |
| 5. | Ṣaḍja Gitā | Ch. 167 Āpaddharma Parva | Vidura | Pāṇḍavas | Āpad Gitā | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826124.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n2381/mode/2up?view=theater) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4850/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/12%20Mahabharat%20Santi%20Parva%20Part%202%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201929/page/n199/mode/2up) |
| 6. | Senajit Gitā | Mokṣadharma Parva | Bhiṣma | Yudhiṣṭhira | Pingālā Gitā | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826132.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n2389/mode/2up?view=theater) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4866/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/12%20Mahabharat%20Santi%20Parva%20Part%202%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201929/page/n239/mode/2up) |
| 7. | Śampāka Gītā | Mokṣadharma Parva | Bhiṣma | Yudhiṣṭhira | Śaspāka Gitā Śaṁpāka Gitā Saṁpāka Gitā | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826134.html), [2](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataMNDutt/page/n2395/mode/2up?view=theater) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4874/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata_with_Hindi_Translation_-_SD_Satwalekar/12%20Mahabharat%20Santi%20Parva%20Part%202%20-%20SD%20Satwalekar%201929/page/n255/mode/2up) |
| 8. | Maṅki Gitā | Anuśāsana Parva | Bhiṣma | Yudhiṣṭhira | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826135.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/4876/mode/2up) |
| 9. | Vicakhnu Gitā | Mokṣadharma Parva 12.265 | Bhiṣma | Yudhiṣṭhira | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826223.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/5104/mode/2up) |
| 10. | Hārīta Gitā | Mokṣadharma Parva - Ch. 278 | Bhiṣma | Yudhiṣṭhira | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826236.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/5142/mode/2up) |
| 11. | Vṛtra Gitā | Mokṣadharma Parva | Bhiṣma | Yudhiṣṭhira | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826237.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/5142/mode/2up) |
| 12. | Parāśara Gitā | Mokṣadharma Parva | Ṛṣi Parāśara [Bhiṣma] | King Janaka [Yudhiṣṭhira] | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826249.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/5194/mode/2up) |
| 13. | Haṁsa Gitā | Mokṣadharma Parva | Ṛṣi Prajāpati Brahmā [Bhiṣma] | Sādhyas [Yudhiṣṭhira] | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826258.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/5216/mode/2up?view=theater) |
| 14. | Bhṛgu Gitā | Kumbakonam Edition Mokṣadharma Parva | Ṛṣi Bhṛgu [Bhiṣma] | Ṛṣi Bhardvāja [Yudhiṣṭhira] | - | English: [1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826140.html) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft/page/n519/mode/2up) |

- ### Some Other Gītās from the Paurāṇika literature:

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Kapila Gītā | Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (ŚB) 3.23-33 | Kapila Muni | Devahūti | - | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/s8yphdyn), [2](https://tinyurl.com/277r2p7p) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/bdfmd262) |
| 2. | Bhikṣu Gītā | ŚB 11.23 | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Uddhava | - | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/3x6u2nvf), [2](https://tinyurl.com/2p9xyh67) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/mr3ffwb7) |
| 3. | Bhramara Gītā | ŚB 10.40-46 | Nārāyaṇa | Akrūra | - | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yc4v3u62), [2](https://tinyurl.com/eh28b4bj) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/4mkt8hpt) |
| 4. | Śruti Gitā | ŚB 10.87(1-50) | Śukadeva | Parikṣit | Vedastutiḥ | English: [159](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/168646), [2](https://tinyurl.com/4m3b4rew) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yckn7snc) |
| 5. | Aila Gītā | ŚB 11.26 | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Uddhava | Ailagītām | English:[1](https://tinyurl.com/e3jfk2d6), [2](https://tinyurl.com/2s39mpu8) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2p94pfwj) |
| 6. | Vyāsa Gītā (same as Īśvara Gītā) | Kūrma Purāṇa | Mahaṛṣi Vyāsa | Various Sages | - | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/ye2x8bf9) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2p8safk7) |
| 7. | Yama Gītā - 1 | Viṣṇu Purāṇa 3.7 | Yamarāja [Mahaṛṣi Parāśara] | Yama's attendant [Maitreya] | - | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yrm2jypu) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n195/mode/2up) |
| 8. | Pṛthvī Gītā | Viṣṇu Purāṇa 4.24 | Earth (goddess) | - | Dharaṇī Gītā | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/2s43bmuk) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/yh9rd8sw) |
| 9. | Pitṛ Gītā | Varāha Purāṇa (Ch. 13) | Pitṛas | - | - | English: [1](https://tinyurl.com/54er3sxm) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/bdh3zp64) |
| 10. | Yama Gītā - 2 | Agni Purāṇa (Ch. 382) | Yamarāja [Agni] | Naciketas [Vasiṣṭha] | - | English:[1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083612.html) Hindi: [1](https://tinyurl.com/4b4mzdb2) |
| 11. | Agastya Gītā | Varāha Purāṇa (Ch. 51 to 67) | Bhagvān Varāha [Ṛṣi Agastya] | Earth (goddess) [King Bhadrāśva] | - | English: [1](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12962/page/n151/mode/2up) Hindi: [1](https://archive.org/details/varaha-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n117/mode/2up?view=theater) |

- ### Miscellaneous/Untraceable Gitas:

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Pāṇḍava Gītā | Independent Work | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Various exalted personalities | Prapanna Gītā | - |
| 2. | Nārada Gītā | Independent Work | Bhagvān Viṣṇu | Nārada | - | - |
| 3. | Guru Gītā | Independent Work | Bhagvān Śiva [Sūta] | Bhagvatī Pārvatī [Sages] | - | - |
| 4. | Yājñavalkya Gītā | Independent Work | Yājñavalkya | Gārgī | - | - |
| 5. | Garbha Gītā | Viṣṇu Purāṇa (non-extant) | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Arjuna | - | - |
| 6. | Jīvanmukta Gītā | Independent Work | Dattātreya | - | - | - |
| 7. | Jñāna Gītā - 1 | Independent Work | - | - | - | - |
| 8. | Jñāna Gītā - 2 | Independent Work | - | - | - | - |
| 9. | Vāsiṣṭha Gītā | Independent Work | Vāsiṣṭha | Rāma | - | - |
| 10. | Arjuna Gītā | Independent Work | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Arjuna | Karma Gītā | - |
| 11. | Siddhānta Gītā (1) & (2) | Atharvaṇaveda Rahasya | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Arjuna | - | - |
| 12. | Karma Gītā | Padma Purāṇa (non-extant) | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Arjuna | - | - |
| 13. | Mokṣa Gītā (1) | - | - | - | - | - |
| 14. | Mokṣa Gītā (2) | - | Svāmī Śivānanda | Śivānanda's Pupils | - | - |
| 15. | Pañcaratna Gītā | - | - | - | - | - |
| 16. | Śrī Sanyāsa Gītā | - | Yājñavalkya | Sages | - | - |
| 17. | Kabīra Gītā | - | - | - | - | - |
| 18. | Jānkī Gītā | untraceable | - | - | - | - |
| 19. | Navavasanta Gītā | untraceable | - | - | - | - |
| 20. | Ārṣa Gītā | Haṁsayogin (author) | - | - | - | - |
| 21. | Kṛṣṇa Gītā | Somnāth (author) | - | - | - | - |
| 22. | The Praṇava Gītā | manuscript lost | - | - | - | - |
| 23. | Ṛbhu Gītā | Skanda Purāṇa (saṁhitā version) | - | - | - | - |
| 24. | Kāvaṣeya Gītā | Brahmānḍa Purāṇa (non-extant) | - | - | - | - |
| 25. | Vālmikī Gītā | - | - | - | - | - |
| 26. | Nārāyaṇa Gītā | Nīlakaṇṭha Brahmacārī (author) | - | - | - | - |
| **27.** | **Pañcādaśa Gītā** | Independent Work | Mutiple personalities | Mutiple personalities | - | - |

- - ##### The Pañcādaśa Gītā collection:

Nine Gitas are distributed over 15 chapters to yield the Pañcādaśa Gītā.

| Sr. No. | Gītā name | Origin Text | Deity / Teacher | Student | Also Known as | Online Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.1 | Kāśyapa Gītā | Independent Work | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Yudhiṣṭhira |  | - |
| 27.2 | Śaunaka Gītā | Independent Work | Śaunaka | Yudhiṣṭhira |  | - |
| 27.3 | Aṣtāvakra Gītā | Independent Work | Sage Lomaśa | - | - | - |
| 27.4 | Nahuṣa Gītā | Independent Work | Yudhiṣṭhira (Nahuṣa) | Nahuṣa (Yudhiṣṭhira) | - | - |
| 27.5 | Sarasva Gītā | Independent Work | Sarasvatī (Goddess) | Tārkṣya (Garuḍa) | - | - |
| 27.6 | Yudhiṣṭhira Gītā | Independent Work | Vaiśampāyana | Janamejaya | - | - |
| 27.7 | Baka Gītā | Independent Work | Ṛṣi Mārkanḍeya | Yudhiṣṭhira | - | - |
| 27.8 | Dharmavyādha Pāṇḍava Gītā | Independent Work | Vyādha |  | - | - |
| 27.9 | Śrīkṛṣṇa Gītā | Mahābhārata | Śrī Kṛṣṇa | Arjuna | - | - |

---

<sup>The Ph.D. scholar notes the following description on the manuscript of the Pañcādaśa Gītā collection, as regards its author: 'upaśamaprakaraṇaṃ
rohitakapradeśāntargataverīgrāmanivāāsi gauḍavaṃśāvataṃsavidhiśāstra paramama **paṇḍita śrī śivavasahāya-sunuravidattaśāstriḥ**'</sup>

---

## Conclusion:

The conclusion drawn by the Ph.D. scholar in their thesis is, therefore -

> [Chapter 7](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/168646/11/10_chapter%207.pdf): 
> **"Statistically reviewing the number of "gītās" in the foregoing pages, they number a little more than a hundred, and the aggregate number of "Ślokas" therein is over twenty thousand"**

IMO, as per the survey done by me personally, if we dig deeper into scriptures, the total counts of the Gītās may very well exceed 200, at the very least.

---

##### Note:

- Wherever possible, I have given appropriate links to buy/read the Gītās, and information as footnotes, etc.
- Since this has been a huge answer to compile, some unintentional mistakes might have crept in while hyperlinking or writing the answer. Please feel free to point out the mistakes in the comments below, so that I may verify and edit those accordingly in the answer.
- Also, to be noted, I have omitted several other Gītās due to a world-limit cap on the answer on the SE.

---

###### Sources Used:

I have utilized several resources in compiling these tables.

- [Gita Sangaraha](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/mode/2up?view=theater) by the Gita Press Gorakhpur,
- Hindu-Scriptures website - [here](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/vedic-knowledge/sacred-scriptures/gita/gita-its-various-kinds) & [here](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/introduction-of-scriptures/type-of-gita).
- PhD thesis - [**A survey of Gītās in Sanskrit literature**](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/168646),
- Sanskrit Documents Website [page on Gītās](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/gita/).
- [The Gītā Literature and its relation with Brahma-Vidyā](https://srkris.wordpress.com/2020/05/04/the-gita-literature-and-its-relation-with-brahma-vidya/), etc.

---

Comment: what is "umpteen" in the 3rd line?

Comment: umpteen means several / many @AmritenduMukhopadhyay  :)

Answer (score 7):

There are many Gitas apart from the most famous Srimad Bhagavad Gita (from Mahabharata).

You can read few of them from [here](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/minigita/texts):

- Ashtavakra Gita
- Avadhuta Gita
- Kapila Gita
- Sriram Gita
- Sruti Gita
- Uddhava Gita
- Vibhishana Gita

Apart from these

- Shiva Gita from Padma Purana ([Is Shiva gita same as Ishvara Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27383/is-shiva-gita-same-as-ishvara-gita))
- Ishvara Gita from Kurma Purana ([Is Shiva gita same as Ishvara Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27383/is-shiva-gita-same-as-ishvara-gita))
- Ganesha Gita from Ganesha Purana ([What is Sri Ganesh Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23373/what-is-sri-ganesh-gita))
- Anu Gita from Mahabharata

---

The post [Where exactly is Ashtavakra Gita found?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32134/where-exactly-is-ashtavakra-gita-found/41022#41022) mentions other Gitas names as follows:

> Sixteen of them are from (a) the Mahābhārata, twenty from (b) the Purāṇas and similar treatises, and four (c) found as independent works untraced to any other known epic or Purāṇa.
>
> Under the group marked (a) are to be found: Utathya-Gītā, Vāmadeva-Gītā, Ṛṣabha-Gītā, Ṣaḍaja-Gītā, Sampāka-Gītā, Maṅki-Gītā, Bodhya-Gītā, Vicakhnu-Gītā, Hārīta-Gītā, Vṛtra-Gītā, Parāśara-Gītā, Haṃsa-Gītā, Brahma-Gītā, Anu-Gītā and Brāhmaṇa-Gītā.
>
> In the group marked (b) are included: two Kapila-Gītās, Haṃsa-Gītā, Bhikṣu-Gītā, Devī-Gītā, Gaṇeśa-Gītā, two Brahma-Gītās, Sūta-Gītā, three Yama-Gītās, Śiva-Gītā, two Rāma-Gītās, Sūrya-Gītā and Vasiṣṭha-Gītā.
>
> Under the group marked (c) come four works: Aṣṭāvakra-Gītā, Avadhūta-Gītā, Uttara-Gītā, and Pāṇḍava-Gītā.