# Summarized Srimada Bhagavad Geeta verses

Tags: bhagavad-gita, resource

I belong to a Hindu family where my family members read Srimada Bhagvad Geeta.

I tried to read it but it has long pages with 'shlokas' and all. Whenever I start to read I'm never able to carry on much. I want to get a summary of the Geeta for a quick reading. I barely have time to go through all the books. What are some resources to get it?

Comment: There are actually various apps. You could read simple translations from app.

Comment: Read Gita translated by Swami Tapasyananda. Every chapter gives the shlokas. The commentary on the shlokas are given at the end of each chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Srimada Bhagvad Geeta, and for that matter any sacred scriptures need to be studied in detail, and understood, and assimilated under the aegis of a qualified preceptor.

To believe that one may understand the Geeta just from a "quick-summary", is in my humble opinion, a counterintuitive approach to the very idea of sacred texts.

That's why we have commentaries (called *Bhashya*) on several texts. These commentaries are detailed in nature, for just a verbatim translation of a verse ('*shlokas*') is not enough to understand the purport, significance and several hidden layers of meanings behind a single verse of the scriptures.

And it's for this particular reason that great *acharyas* of various sects and school of thoughts have written detailed commentaries on these texts, especially for Srimada Bhagvad Geeta.

So, I'd suggest to atleast read the complete full translations of the Geeta, rather than some "quick-summary" to atleast make something worthwhile out of the text.

As it is, there are various Geetas in existence, apart from the most popular Srimada Bhagvad Geeta by Sri Krishna (found in the Mahabharata), like Ishvara Geeta by Shiva (Kurma Purana), Devi Geeta by goddess Shakti, Ganesha Geeta, Surya Geeta, etc.

Refer my answer on this question to get an idea of multitudes of Geetas - [How many Gitas are there?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51230/17833)

---

However, some useful resources for your cause maybe as follows.

- [Essence of Srimada Bhagvad Geeta by Kamakoti peetham](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/Essence%2520of%2520Shrimad%2520Bhagavad%2520Gita.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiD4s7-7Kb4AhUk7TgGHde2D20QFnoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0hweTzqdse4IBfaFzEgAZc)
- [A verse by verse Translation of the Srimada Bhagvad Geeta by various scholars and acharyas hosted by IIT-Kanpur](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1&htrskd=1&httyn=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&etssa=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
- [BHAGAVAD GITA By Sri Swami Sivananda](https://www.dlshq.org/download/bhagavad-gita/). *You may read the preface and introduction for a basic idea.*
- [Bhagavad-gītā As It Is](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/) by the Gaudiya Vaishnava sects's acharya from ISCKON. *The summarized version of each chapter by ISCKON maybe accessed [from here](https://www.iskconbooks.com/chapter-wise-summary-of-bhagavad-gita-as-it-is/) or [here](https://www.krishna.com/info/bhagavad-gita-it-chapter-summary)*.
- Yet another site which gives translation of each verse and commentaries from various acharyas of different sects is [BhagvadGeetaUs](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/). _They also have a ["summarized version" here](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/summary-of-the-bhagavad-gita/).
- [**A concise summary of each chapter by Swami Parmarthananda Sarasvati**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.vedanta.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/SwParam_3Gita-1-18_Verses-Summary-Book_ENA5.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjZz7Ci8Kb4AhWzSWwGHULLCEY4FBAWegQIERAB&usg=AOvVaw0kuBaWx9j7xJDYIqTEySf1).
- [Summary of Srimada Bhagvad Geeta by Hindu website](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/summary.asp)

---

However, despite having given above a non-exhaustive list of resources on Srimada Bhagavad Geeta, I'd recommend and plead to read detailed commentaries in Geeta or atleast watch relevant videos by acharyas on the same. For instance [the Vedanta Hub website](https://www.vedantahub.org/bhagavad-gita/) enlists several resources of detailed commentaries and exposition, in text, transcripts and videos format on the Srimada Bhagvad Geeta by several acharyas, swamis and qualified preceptors of the Vedanta.